# Choropleth map fails to render shading for geojson boundaries

Tags: csv, geo, choropleth, folium

Folium renders the choropleth map with the police force boundaries but these are all grey and not colour matched for the data in the dataframe.

I have also ensured the new version of the documentation is followed i.e. folium.Choropleth.
I have also checked to make sure I am key_on='feature.properties.pfa16nm' by checking the json in geojson.io
Feature is spelt with a capital when checking the geojson however when I change it to this I get an error and no map renders. I have also renamed the file to only have the geojson as an extension and that didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import json
import os
adults_trafficked = pd.read_excel('Adults trafficked.xlsx')
force_boundaries = 'Police_Force_Areas_December_2016_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.geojson.json'

m = folium.Map([52.6333, -1.1333], zoom_start=4)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=force_boundaries,
    data=adults_trafficked,
    columns=['Police_Force', 'Adults_Exploited'],
    key_on='feature.properties.pfa16nm',
    threshold_scale=[0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175],
    fill_color='BuPu',
    legend_name='Trafficked Humans',
).add_to(m)
m
```

Output that I am getting
[image]

I expect the Leaflet map to render with each police boundary shaded to the appropriate level based on the dataframe column data. The Chorpleth map renders perfectly with the boundaries however these are all grey and do not contain the tonal colour range one would expect. Please [find the code, data and the json link here.](https://github.com/Crime-Analytics/Human_Trafficking)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, not able to find the solution. Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563700/choropleth-map-is-not-showing-color-variation-in-the-output

Comment: Please post your data and the geojson data on your drive and then share the link. The link that you have shared is for a page. We don't have enough time to search for the download button. Please post the minimal version of your problem so that we can help you quickly and effectively.

Comment: Please update the data and geojson file so that I can answer your question.

Comment: I have created a github with the necessary information https://github.com/Crime-Analytics/Human_Trafficking.git thank you for your anticipated help. My initial thinking is that I will have to edit the json file manually.

Comment: The data file doesn't match the `pfa16nm` in the json file. If you can make them match, your code should work. For example, excel file has `Cumbria Constabulary` whereas the json file has `Cumbria`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the excel file doesn't match the json file. When you use

```
columns=['Police_Force', 'Adults_Exploited'],
key_on='feature.properties.pfa16nm',
```

the Police_Force should match the pfa16nm in your json file.

This code will give you the `pfa16nms` in your json.

```
import json 
policejson = json.load(open('Police_Force_Areas_December_2016_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.geojson.json')) 
for x in policejson['features'] : 
    print (x['properties']['pfa16nm'])
```

Then you need to make fix your excel file, and make sure that the `Police_Force` column  matches the names in your json file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer worked perfectly; a valuable lesson learnt! I will update my new github with the working code soon.

Comment: Himanshu Poddar I have carefully worked through your answer and it also worked for me and allowed me to edit in pandas saving me time correcting the mis-alignment of police force names. I will combine this new learning into a newer notebook and upload to github, I have given proper thanks after your answer to acknowledge this. Thank you for your time and  education.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of the key and the name of the Police_Force in your database aren't matching. So after analysing your data as well as the json file I did some pre processing with your data so that the name matches with the key in our json file.

Here is a full fledge solution to your question.

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import folium
import json
import webbrowser

# read data
adults_trafficked = pd.read_excel('Adults trafficked.xlsx')

# Pre processing of data
adults_trafficked['Police_Force'] = adults_trafficked['Police_Force'].replace('Police|Constabulary','', regex=True, ).replace('&','and', regex=True)
adults_trafficked.loc[adults_trafficked['Police_Force'] == "Metropolitan  Service",'Police_Force' ] = 'Metropolitan Police'

# remove any trailing or leading white spaces
adults_trafficked['Police_Force'] = adults_trafficked['Police_Force'].str.strip()

# border json file 
force_boundaries = 'Police_Force_Areas_December_2016_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.geojson.json'

# choropleth map
m = folium.Map([52.6333, -1.1333], zoom_start=7)

m.choropleth(
    geo_data=force_boundaries,
    data=adults_trafficked,
    columns=['Police_Force', 'Adults_Exploited'],
    key_on='feature.properties.pfa16nm',
    threshold_scale=[0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200],
    fill_color='BuPu',
    legend_name='Trafficked Humans',
)
m.save('map.html')
webbrowser.open('map.html')
```

Note that the length of threshold_scale cannot be more than 6. I can see yours was 8. Also there are only 44 police_force data in your json file while the length of your dataset is 47. So those 3 data which didn't match were ignored by folium. 
This is what you will get

[image]

In case if you have trouble understanding any part of code please comment below.

Comment: Thank you kindly this also worked for me and provided the means to change the dataframe using pandas. I kept the folium.Choropleth() to avoid the deprecation warning. Thank you also for the note on x6 length on the threshold scale I will keep this in mind. I also discovered that the 3 missing values are ok to ignore. There are good reasons for this as it only captured points for England and Wales; so Police Scotland and Belfast are not included and finally British Transport Police do not have a geographical boundary so that explains that point. Your work is appreciated.